# Split Batches if Batch is above a certain size. System.schedulebatch

Tags: apex, email, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

A bit of background, I am looking to make a work around for the governor limits for daily email usage. As it stands I am able to schedule my batch of emails to send but I am having trouble splitting the batch into 2 batches if it is above 4,000 emails. What I am looking to do is schedule a batch every 24 hours containing the 4,000 - 5,000 emails that need to be sent out.

As it stands I am pretty close but need a little help getting this over the line on how to accomplish this. My current class which controls the send out is:

**SendReportsController**

```
public with sharing class SendReportPageController {
public Boolean sendDashboard {get;set;}
public Boolean sendLocationCO2Report {get;set;}
public Boolean sendGroupCO2Report {get;set;}
public Boolean sendPartnerReport {get;set;}
public Boolean sendLinkedReport {get;set;}
Integer minutesFromNow = 30;
public SendReportPageController(){
    sendDashboard           = false; 
    sendLocationCO2Report   = false;
    sendGroupCO2Report      = false;
    sendPartnerReport       = false;
    sendLinkedReport        = false;
}


public PageReference doSend(){
    if(!sendDashboard && !sendLocationCO2Report && !sendGroupCO2Report && !sendPartnerReport && !sendLinkedReport){
        Apexpages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'You have to select at least a report type!');
        Apexpages.addMessage(msg);
        return null;
    }

    String msgVal = '';
    Boolean isSent = false;
    integer i = 1;
     if(BatchSendReports.isAvailableApexJob()){
        BatchSendReports batch      = new BatchSendReports();
        while(BatchSendReports.isAvailableApexJob()){
        batch.sendDashboard         = sendDashboard;
        batch.sendLocationCO2Report = sendLocationCO2Report;
        batch.sendGroupCO2Report    = sendGroupCO2Report;
        batch.sendPartnerReport     = sendPartnerReport;
        batch.sendLinkedReport      = sendLinkedReport;
        //100 because single email allow send 100 records per mail
        //Database.executeBatch(batch, 100);
        //
        //
        System.scheduleBatch(batch, 'EmailBatch in ' + minutesFromNow + ' mins', minutesFromNow, 100); 
        //System.schedule('emailJob ' + i, '0 0/'+ minutesFromNow + ' * * * ?', batch);
        minutesFromNow = minutesFromNow + 1440; // for new batch add new minutes
        msgVal = 'Sending report is in progress.';
        isSent = true;
        i++;
        System.debug('i = ' + i);
        } 
    }else{
        msgVal = 'Apex job isnot available. Please try again later.';
    }

    Apexpages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(isSent ? ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM : ApexPages.Severity.Warning, msgVal);
    Apexpages.addMessage(msg);
    return null;
}
}
```

If you wish to see the BatchSendReports class just let me know and ill add it in, but from what I can tell the logic to accomplish this should be done in the controller?

EDIT//

**BatchSendReports**

```
public class BatchSendReports implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    private ID accid;
    private static final String DASHBOARD_TEMP  = 'Monthly_Location_Dashboard';
    private static final String MONTHLY_TEMP    = 'Monthly_Recycling_Report';
    private static final String GROUP_TEMP      = 'Group_Recycling_Report';
    private static final String PARTNER_TEMP    = 'Partner_Recycling_Report';
    private static final String LINKED_TEMP     = 'Linked_Recycling_Report';

    private static final String DASHBOARD_REPORT= 'dashboard';
    private static final String MONTHLY_REPORT  = 'co2 report';
    private static final String GROUP_REPORT    = 'enqix spreadsheet';
    private static final String PARTNER_REPORT  = 'partnership co2 report';
    private static final String LINKED_REPORT   = 'linked account co2 report';

    private Map<String, String> mapReportTypeEmailTemplate = new Map<String, String>{   DASHBOARD_REPORT=> DASHBOARD_TEMP,
                                                                                        MONTHLY_REPORT  => MONTHLY_TEMP,
                                                                                        GROUP_REPORT    => GROUP_TEMP,
                                                                                        PARTNER_REPORT  => PARTNER_TEMP,
                                                                                        LINKED_REPORT   => LINKED_TEMP};
    public Boolean sendDashboard            {get;set;}
    public Boolean sendLocationCO2Report    {get;set;}
    public Boolean sendGroupCO2Report       {get;set;}
    public Boolean sendPartnerReport        {get;set;}
    public Boolean sendLinkedReport         {get;set;}



//for testing
public BatchSendReports(ID accid){
    this.accid = accid;
    ////If run from test, default value will true
    this.sendDashboard          = Test.isRunningTest(); 
    this.sendLocationCO2Report  = Test.isRunningTest();
    this.sendGroupCO2Report     = Test.isRunningTest();
    this.sendPartnerReport      = Test.isRunningTest();
    this.sendLinkedReport       = Test.isRunningTest();
}

public BatchSendReports(){
    //If run from test, default value will true
    this.sendDashboard          = Test.isRunningTest();
    this.sendLocationCO2Report  = Test.isRunningTest();
    this.sendGroupCO2Report     = Test.isRunningTest();
    this.sendPartnerReport      = Test.isRunningTest();
    this.sendLinkedReport       = Test.isRunningTest();
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    Set<String> reportTypes = new Set<String>();

    if(sendDashboard)           reportTypes.add(DASHBOARD_REPORT);
    if(sendLocationCO2Report)   reportTypes.add(MONTHLY_REPORT);
    if(sendGroupCO2Report)      reportTypes.add(GROUP_REPORT);
    if(sendPartnerReport)       reportTypes.add(PARTNER_REPORT);
    if(sendLinkedReport)        reportTypes.add(LINKED_REPORT);

    String query = 'Select Name, Main_Contact_Email__c, Report_Type__c From Account ';
    String condition = ' Where Report_Type__c != null AND Report_Type__c in:reportTypes ' + (accid != null ? ' AND id=:accid ' : '') ;

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query + condition);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){

    //get all related email templates
    Map<String, String> mapEmailTemplates = new Map<String, String>();
    for (EmailTemplate et : [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName in:mapReportTypeEmailTemplate.values()]) {
        mapEmailTemplates.put(et.DeveloperName, et.Id);
    }

    //get all Contacts related Account that its Receive_Global_Report__c = true
    Map<String, List<String>> mapAccConGlobalReport = new Map<String, List<String>>();
    for(Contact con: [Select Email, AccountId 
                        From Contact 
                        Where Receive_Global_Report__c = true 
                            AND Email != null 
                            AND AccountID in: (List<Account>) scope])
    {
        if(!mapAccConGlobalReport.containsKey(con.AccountId)){
            mapAccConGlobalReport.put(con.AccountId, new List<String>());
        }
        mapAccConGlobalReport.get(con.AccountId).add(con.Email);
    }

    List<OrgWideEmailAddress> orgWilds = [Select Id From OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName ='First Mile' AND IsAllowAllProfiles = true limit 1];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<ResultReportSent__c> lstRecordResults = new List<ResultReportSent__c>();

    for(Account acc: (List<Account>) scope){
        String reportType = acc.Report_Type__c.toLowerCase();
        Boolean isGeneratePDF   = mapReportTypeEmailTemplate.containsKey(reportType) && !mapReportTypeEmailTemplate.get(reportType).equalsIgnoreCase(DASHBOARD_TEMP);
        Boolean isGroup         = reportType.equalsIgnoreCase(GROUP_REPORT);
        Boolean isPartner       = reportType.equalsIgnoreCase(PARTNER_REPORT);
        Boolean isLinked        = reportType.equalsIgnoreCase(LINKED_REPORT);

        //get email template by Account report type
        String emailTemp = mapReportTypeEmailTemplate.containsKey(reportType) ? mapReportTypeEmailTemplate.get(reportType) : '';
        if(emailTemp == '') continue;

        String emailTemplateId = mapEmailTemplates.containsKey(emailTemp) ? mapEmailTemplates.get(emailTemp) : '';
        if(emailTemplateId == '') continue;

        List<String> lstReciptients = new List<String>();

        //if Account report type is Dashboard or Monthly report, it required acc.Main_Contact_Email__c
        if((reportType.equalsIgnoreCase(DASHBOARD_REPORT) || reportType.equalsIgnoreCase(MONTHLY_REPORT)) && acc.Main_Contact_Email__c == null) continue;

        if(acc.Main_Contact_Email__c != null){
            lstReciptients.add(acc.Main_Contact_Email__c);
            System.debug('Email : ' + acc.Main_Contact_Email__c);
        }

        //when the "Group Recycling Report" or "Partner Recycling Report" OR "Linked Recycled Report" is pressed,
        //any contacts for that account that "Receive Global Report" checked will get the group report.
        if((isGroup || isPartner || isLinked) && mapAccConGlobalReport.containsKey(acc.Id)){
            lstReciptients.addall(mapAccConGlobalReport.get(acc.Id));
        }

        //record the results by report type of the number sent for each batch
        lstRecordResults.add(new ResultReportSent__c(   Account__c = acc.Id,
                                                        Status__c = 'Sent',
                                                        Date_Sent__c = System.today(),
                                                        Name = System.now().format('MMMM yyyy') + ' Report'));
        //prepare email
        lstMails.add(SendingEmailUtils.generateEmail(emailTemplateId, acc.Id, lstReciptients, orgWilds, isGeneratePDF, isGroup, isPartner, isLinked));
    }

    if(!lstMails.isEmpty()){
        try {
            Messaging.sendEmail(lstMails);

            if(!lstRecordResults.isEmpty()){
                insert lstRecordResults;
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('****** Error: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

} 

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        AsyncApexJob asyn = [Select Status, CreatedBy.Email, TotalJobItems, NumberOfErrors From AsyncApexJob Where id=:BC.getJobId() limit 1];
        String[] toAddresses = new String[]{asyn.CreatedBy.Email};

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setSubject('Batch Sending Report ' + asyn.Status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('The batch Apex job processed ' + asyn.TotalJobItems + ' batches with ' + asyn.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setBccAddresses(new List<String>{/*'customers@thefirstmile.co.uk'*/'ben.allington@pracedo.com'});
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}

public static Boolean isAvailableApexJob(){
    return 5 > [Select count() From AsyncApexJob where Status in ('Processing', 'Preparing')];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You mention wanting to split this into two separate batches. I'm not quite certain I follow what you're trying to do with that. Is that so they can run simultaneously under two different class names? Your flex queue won't allow that to happen. Your org can only consume so much of the Pod's resources at any given time. Tracking limits for the single class is an entirely different matter. That I can answer.

Comment: I'm looking to make a work around for guvenor limits so say I want to batch 10,000 emails I need to split it and send 5,000 now and 5,000 scheduled in 24 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different things I think you're going to want to do here.

1. Track your email limits using a public class that holds a public static integer which can be accessed by every batch in your batchable class.
2. Pass that back to your controller using a public static boolean should you get close to exceeding your limits.
3. The method to update the latter should be contained in your batch class.
4. Both of these should be stored as variables on the same utility class.

Here's what I have in mind:

```
Public with sharing class EmailLimitsTracking {

    public static boolean isAvailableLimitsEmail = false;

    public static integer availableEmailLimits = 0; 

}
```

Methods to add to your batch class

```
calculateAvailableEmailLimits(){

    EmailLimitsTracking.availableEmailLimits = ( getLimitEmailInvocations() - getLimitEmailInvocations()); 

    if(EmailLimitsTracking.availableEmailLimits > 5){

        EmailLimitsTracking.isAvailableLimitsEmail = true;

    }else {

        EmailLimitsTracking.isAvailableLimitsEmail = false;

    }
}
```

For reference:

> **getEmailInvocations()**
>
> Returns the number of email invocations (such as sendEmail) that *have been* called.
>
> **getLimitEmailInvocations()**
>
> Returns the total number of email invocation (such as sendEmail) that *can be* called.

From here, you should be able to figure out how you want to implement turning off your batches when you get close to reaching your limits. It's important that you keep in mind that limits are for a rolling 24 hour period and do not reset themselves at midnight or at a specific time.

**EDIT:**

The more I think about this, you may want to consider writing these jobs to a temporary `job holder object` (don't forget to add a method to delete jobs upon success at the end of each batch), then use a dispatcher class to send them out in batches to your queue as limits become available. The pattern to use would be similar to what's described in [Answer : How to set time limit between queued jobs?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/157735/2212) except a queuable would call a dispatcher class when finished if more email limits are available and there are more jobs still left in the temporary `job holder object` that haven't yet been queued.

Comment: @crmpogdev I have implemented something but it appears when scheduling the getemail and getlimit don't update as there is nothing that has been called

Comment: That's true! The batch operations are asynchronous and won't cause an update to occur until the individual batches are actually running. Once you have 5 or more in the system that are running, you should then begin to see these updates occur. In that sense it's not much different than your `isBatchAvailable`. It will change as batches are in the queue, as they execute. Because it's a rolling 24 hrs, once started this shouldn't be an issue.